# Laravel 5.4 relationship - using the right type

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I have 3 tables:
users, user_addrs, orders

The orders table have these fields:
user_id, shipping_addr_id, billing_addr_id

In the UserAddr model I have:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

In the Order model I have:

```
public function userShippingAddr()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserAddr', 'shipping_addr_id');
}

public function userBillingAddr()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserAddr', 'billing_addr_id');
}
```

Is this the right way to do it or should I use a different relationship type?

Comment: what columns does `user_addrs` have? And what is your goal? What data do you want to store? users, orders, addresses? One address per user or multiple? one address per order? I would not name a table for shipping addresses `user_addrs`, that is a bit confusing.

Comment: user_addrs has these columns:
id, user_id, addr_type, addr_line_1, suburb, city etc. I want to store shipping address and billing address for a user and a user can have many of each. Each order has one user one billing address id and one shipping address id

Comment: You have users and orders. Each of them with addresses. Maybe you could use "One To Many (Polymorphic)" for that https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 0):

In the UserAddr has 'id' as primary key than model you should have:

In the UserAddr model you should have:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order','shipping_addr_id');
    or
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order','billing_addr_id');

}
```

In the Order model you should have:

```
public function userShippingAddr()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserAddr', 'id','shipping_addr_id');
}

public function userBillingAddr()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserAddr', 'id', 'billing_addr_id');
}
```

using `return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

read docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thank you, but I can't put or in the order function, it's gives an error, and I need to connect to both addresses for each order. I read the documentation before I posted here and got confused with all the options, that's why I asked for advice here.

Comment: This is the SQL I need: SELECT * FROM orders join users on orders.user_id = users.id join user_addrs on users.id = user_addrs.user_id where addr_type = 'S' and status = 3 //Status is a field on the orders table

Comment: use can use functional query on a relationship

Comment: please post a separate question if you have any other issue would be difficult and pointless answering if it cannot be reused by others

Comment: phpdroid, not sure what you mean use can use, and not sure why you want me to post another question when I'm still on the same question. Anyway, thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this and I'm not sure if it is 100% what you want. But it should give you a good starting point.

---

## 1. What do you want?

1. A user can have many addresses => `(users)  - many -> (addresses)`
2. A order has one user => `(orders) - one -> (users)`
3. A order has one billing address => `(orders) - one billing -> (addresses)`
4. A order has one shipping address => `(orders) - one shipping -> (addresses)`

## 2. What tables do you need?

- users

  - id
  - ...
- orders

  - id
  - users_id
  - billing_addresses_id
  - shipping_addresses_id
- addresses

  - id
  - zip
  - city
  - street
  - ...
- addresses_users

  - users_id
  - addresses_id
  - type? (billing|shipping)

## 3. How should the models look like?

### 1. A user can have many addresses => `(users)  - many -> (addresses)`

```
class Users extends Model {
    // ...
    public function addresses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Addresses')->withPivot('type');
    }
}
```

### 2. A order has one user => `(orders) - one -> (users)`

```
class Orders extends Model {
    // ...
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users');
    }
}
```

### 3. A order has one billing address => `(orders) - one billing -> (addresses)`

```
class Orders extends Model {
    // ...
    public function billing_address() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Addresses', 'id', 'billing_addresses_id');
    }
}
```

### 4. A order has one shipping address => `(orders) - one shipping -> (addresses)`

```
class Orders extends Model {
    // ...
    public function shipping_address() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Addresses', 'id', 'shipping_addresses_id_addresses_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sigal Zahavi have you tested it? Please ask if you have any further questions